# Performance of java if-else with return statement

Tags: java, performance, if-statement

```
private String getString1(int n){

    if (n == 0) {
        return "ZERO";
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return "ONE";
    }
    if(n == 2) {
        return "TWO";
    }
    return "-NA-";
}

private String getString2(int n){

    if (n == 0) {
        return "ZERO";
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return "ONE";
    } else if(n == 2) {
        return "TWO";
    } else
        return "-NA-";
}
```

I have the above methods getString1(int) and getString2(int). Both will give the same o/p. 
But which one is the most efficient way of using? In there any difference in term of performance?

Comment: No, there isn't. Stop worrying about performance for such trivial details. Use the one that you find the most readable.

Comment: Use a [`switch` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead.

Comment: Ask yourself "if the input is zero, how many checks need to be done?" and so on for all other inputs. If you do that for both examples, you'll see the number of checks is the same, therefore the performance is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as cpu time - **NO DIFFERENCE**. The compiler will probably optimise them to exactly the same byte-code anyway.

As far as technical debt is concerned - as soon as a real developer looks at this code and replaces it with:

```
private static final String[] numbers = {"ZERO", "ONE", "TWO"};

private String getString(int n) {
    return n >= 0 && n < numbers.length? numbers[n]:"-NA-");
}
```

you've just cost your company money.